# Call oracle functions using jdbc node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, jdbc

I'm using [jdbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) node module in order to connect to oracle and call some functions declared there.

I configured the connection like:

```js
{
    libpath: './ojdbc6_g.jar',
    drivername: 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
    url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.53:1521:orcl',
    // optionally
    user: 'test',
    password: 'oraclerac'
}
```

Then, I call the function as following:

```js
var query = "{ call oracleFunction(input) }";

var genericQueryHandler = function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (results) {
            console.log(results);
        }
    };

jdbc.open(function (err, conn) {

  jdbc.executeQuery(query, genericQueryHandler);

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
{ [Error: Error running instance method
    java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 3
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.handleODBC(OracleSql.java:1886)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.parse(OracleSql.java:1733)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSql(OracleSql.java:438)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSqlBytes(OracleSql.java:942)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:197)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1245)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1585)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1810)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:1281)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
] cause: {} }
```

I dont know what is wrong with that code.